# Problem using mosfet to reset a microcontroller (drain voltage too low)

Tags: mosfet, esp8266, reset

I'm experimenting with a learning project, where I want to generate a "reset pulse" (from high-low-high) to trigger a reset of a microcontroller, an ESP8266. This is the only way to wake this chip from deep sleep (hard reset). Disclaimer: I know about the more powerful ESP32, but I still want to try to understand why this setup is not working before moving on ;)

So the idea is to trigger a mosfet on every button state change, both when it goes from open to closed (0 to 3.3V), and when it goes from closed to open (3.3V to 0). To achieve this, I've got some help on ##electronics to set up the following [simulation](https://falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=CQAgjCAMB0l3BWEDYCYDMqDsrUE4AOLSAgsJPPZZSZAUwFowwAoAJRABZMRUSueYVASijOtdNHSjaMBCwDmyLADZepZWsyyoLAM4DUvfglXGROgGYBDADZ66LAE6b1I02r4Xw8FgGNXLxAVDSDZWHhISmiY2MoQSXxorFI8HAIESCwoCNYXMEhUTgS%20HyKuTm8CyMhFYNCNEJFtGRZ0EMCTMyERCFoAcQAFAEkAeQAdPQAHAEsAOzqC8s5KsuKEIVaXJq48NR2PUWragMPOPfqRc7VwyIhE6IJuGNSLmDg812uvsBufOH0hl2ajOb3AIBs9kcSm4Rm%20sOC-Fk7B%20ILM6CeMi4EikWLkLAAJiAsO1zCA8JsgkYCXQbABXWwAF0JxNJ3wpcIu1Np1gZzIA7uTKfwOSVkYLRezNi1au0RKKWtURLhisiiSTPBoNWTufSmXVtcIRNqZbp1aTDtrvrrefqlNrLaSVEjdIKdkFDUiWG6NN8rW8WJY1mKfBoWoJoEh3qhvcGWgrSrV8iRmpBigUNGAzLROMQARwM71uinwMIseIEridPilIWgXWNkZkdsGiJ3S7jnUDmYds7vEnQ81SXWEbRO3LSwQJGnwJhU%20nRGw6A5GZNZgsAEYVIsghAgzh9FgAD234BwNDHWCQxXKAGUAOqfHrT9PCS9-Y61QXPs9qOtZm5YzrdAZx-EDVRYAB7LhglVbFCGod5IBUVAo14GD0Cg8AqF%20UQjzISBNiQuBVHwdA8E4BB0CEJAVGgBcjCMBg-yoaQmywstcOkcQEPecjkNQnJ4DAPAqJo9DWGg9B0z%20Hj3GCeiEnQ6SEhYIA)

[image]

Consider both switches of "SW1" to open and close simultaneously (doesn't have to be exact timing). This is for a simple door sensor, so I couldn't easily use a DPDT switch. And in any case, please refer to my above disclaimer whenever this seems over-engineered or just odd. I just want to learn why this is working (very much) different in real life, than in the sim.

In the sim, the drain of the mosfet stays at VCC while the mosfet is off, and goes to 0 while it is on, giving a nice high-low-high pulse. In my actual setup, I have only 0.6V at the drain when the mosfet (BS170) is off. Is this mosfet very different from the one set up in the sim? As it seems to me, this voltage is pulling the RST pin of the ESP low at all times so it just never runs.

Components used are:

- 3.3V power supply
- BS170 N-channel mosfet
- 2.2nF caps (I didn't have 10uF ceramic ones)
- 1N4001 diodes

[image: Actual setup]

[image: Yellow: gate voltage (button click), blue: drain voltage (0.6V to 0)]Yellow: gate voltage (button click), blue: drain voltage (0.6V to 0)

**Updated schematic after answers below:**

[image]

Comment: You've maybe got drain and source swapped on your real circuit.

Comment: Pretty sure that's not the case... I've added a photo of my actual setup :)

Comment: Following on from Andy's suggestion are you sure it is a BS170? Other similar devices have the drain and source swapped. (eg https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/cd00005134.pdf). Why not just try rotating the device 180 deg. It is acting as if it is wired backwards.

Comment: You can pull your NMOS out of your circuit, measure if there is a diode between source and drain, to make sure if your NMOS is working fine.

Comment: The component is marked "BS 170 QG 95". Rotating it 180 deg does indeed bring the drain (which I assumed was the source) up to 3.3V, as expected. So strange, as all image search on "BS170 pinout" identify the pins the other way around

Comment: @greybeard when you say "lower pull down", do you mean the 1k to ground (on source)? It should be greater than the 47k to VCC (on drain)?
Also, sorry for the missing caption on the scope image; seems I added it only to the alt-text of the image

Comment: After rotating the mosfet, I no longer see any "response" on the scope when the gate goes from 0 to 3.3V (the yellow line). The blue line (response on the drain) is now only a flat line, constant at 3.3V. @WillisLin I'll try to check the mosfet (diode) as you suggested. Maybe it's broken?

Comment: Just change the MOSFET. All MOSFETs like this have diodes and testing it is superfluous. Buy from a recognized supplier and not some shady internet source. It sounds like an incorrectly marked p-channel MOSFET.

Comment: I did a diode check on my DMM (as best I could) by first discharging the mosfet, then measuring no continuity between source and drain. Then, after turning mosfet on by touching "red lead" to gate, I measure 0.04 between drain and source. This only works (as per the youtube video hehe) if I identify the pins how you guys suggested (rotated 180 deg), so I understand this is part of the problem. However, I'm having the problem described above, with flat 3.3V on drain now -- it no longer seems to "react" to changing gate voltage.

Comment: I changed the 1k pull down (on the lower switch) with 470k, such that it is larger than the 1k pull up, and now the lower button seems to work! Please note that I'm using 2.2nF caps -- not 10uF -- so maybe any "pulse" I was generating was too short/brief to trigger a reset?

Comment: @greybeard if this (check diode, and rotate it), as well as up the pull-down resistor values, was posted as an answer I could hit "accept" :) And thanks a lot, everyone!!

Comment: (What is that *##electronics* you got help from?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Is this [MOSFET marked BS170] very different from the one set up in the [simulation]?`

The simulation uses a \$V_{GS(th)}\$ of 1.5 V.
According to the onsemi datasheet, the gate voltage \$V_{GS(th)}\$ for 1 mA drain current with \$V_{DS} = V_{GS}\$ is 0.8 V min/2.1 V typ/3 V max.
A design should work for all devices within the specified range of device parameters.

The behaviour you describe (0.6 V max) is typical of a MOSFET with drain and source swapped and body diode conducting; the oscillogram is even more telling:
For a short time, \$V_{GS}\$ is high enough to lower the channel resistance for an even lower output voltage.

From steady state, opening the upper contact lets a 1k resistor pull down the left side of a capacitor "clamped to ground" with a diode on the right:
The right side will drop to the diode's forward voltage for the decaying current.
Closing the contact yanks the left side to 3.3 V resulting in 3.3 V (- Vf) peak on the right.

Opening the lower contact lets current through the 1k pull-up flow through the capacitor *and a 1k pull-down* to ground, both resistors effectively a voltage divider:
The voltage peak at the pull-down will be 1.65 V with a capacitor initially discharged.
For a decent peak voltage, the pull-down's value needs to be considerably higher than the pull-up's.

From the peak voltages there is another *diode drop* to consider for "the OR-diodes".

---

I don't understand "fulstad's" simulation result for closing the lower contact.

I can't imagine any amount of parameter adjustments turning this *diode OR + MOSFET* into a reliable reset generator, let alone with the requirement
*both when it goes from open to closed, and when it goes from closed to open*.